# What does {} mean when inspecting a variable?

Tags: c#

I have the something similar to the following code that looks up a member using reflection:

```
private static object GetPrivateFieldValue(object target, string fieldName)
{
    var targetType = target.GetType();
    var targetField = targetType.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (targetField == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("{0}.{1} is null", targetType.Name, fieldName));
    }
    var fieldValue = targetField.GetValue(target);
    return fieldValue;
}
```

In once particular case I use it as follows:

```
var values = (object[]) GetPrivateFieldValue(currentItem, "_values");
foreach (var fieldName in recordsReaderCacheEntry.FieldNames)
{
    var valueIndex = Array.IndexOf(recordsReaderCacheEntry.FieldNames, fieldName);
    var value = values[valueIndex];
    currentRecordDictionary.Add(fieldName, value);
}
```

This works fine to a point, it falls down if one of the values is empty in the original object, its represented as `{}` in the values array.

I want to be able to check if value equals `{}`, so I can replace it with null ideally.

This, however, does not compile:

```
if (value == {})
```

Similarly the below don't either:

```
if (value == object) //obviously
if (value == new {}) //obviously
if (value == new object{}) //i hoped it might work
if (value == null) //this never matches as strictly speaking its not null
```

EDIT

Added crucial context changing detail to the question... sorry guys.

Comment: So you want to know if the array is empty, if so then set it to null? Why not simply: `if(values != null && values.Length == 0) values = null;`

Comment: An expression has some value (like a variable or function or literal). Braces cannot be evaluated, hence braces are not expressions.

Comment: You come from an inferior JavaScript background, don't you?

Comment: @Jeroen I know that's a joke, but JavaScript is really powerful in the right hands.

Comment: Sorry i've missed out a vital part of the question, ill update it now

Comment: Use the debugger. Type `value.GetType()` in the Immediate Window. The `{}` is just the `ToString()` representation of the object.

Comment: @CodeCaster {Name = "DBNull" FullName = "System.DBNull"} right that should sort it :) check if its that type...

Comment: if (value.GetType() is DBNull) doesnt work, states that "given expression is never of provided type"

Comment: @TomRiley, simply check `if(value is DBNull)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: for updated question:

It looks like you are trying to compare your `value` field against `DBNull`, in your current code you can do:

```
var value = values[valueIndex];
if(value is DBNull)
{
   value = null;
}
```

---

(Previous Answer)

If you are doing that:

```
var values = (object[]) GetPrivateFieldValue(currentItem, "_values");
```

Than it means you are getting back an array *(may be an empty one)* to check for an empty array use [`IEnumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like:

```
if(!values.Any())
{
   //empty array found
    values = null; //set it to null
}
```

You can also compare the `Length` of returned array, Also it would be better to use `as` operator for casting like:

```
var values = GetPrivateFieldValue(currentItem, "_values") as object[];
if(values != null && values.Length == 0)
{
   //Empty found
     values = null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i've missed out a vital part of the question, ill update it now

Comment: @TomRiley, so from your question, Do you want to check if for line `var value = values[valueIndex];` , the variable `value` is an array and if it is empty assign it null ? I

Comment: values[valueIndex] can be of many types, but if it is DBNull i want to set it to null

Comment: use `if(values[valueIndex] is DBNull)`